# I face a problem while writing into a csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

```
for container in containers:
    job_title=container.findAll('h2',{'class':'css-m604qf'})
    job_title=job_title[0].text.strip()
    
    company=container.findAll('a',{'class':'css-17s97q8'})
    company=company[0].text.strip()
    job_type=container.findAll('span',{'class':'css-1ve4b75 eoyjyou0'})
    job_type=job_type[0].text.strip()
    g=job_title +","+ company +","+ job_type +"\n"
    file.write(g)
file.close()
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you get an error or unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a `csv.writer()` rather than trying to append commas. This would stop any problems if any of your 3 items also contain commas. For example:

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer()
    csv_output.writerow(['Job title', 'Company', 'Job type'])

    for container in containers:
        job_title = container.findAll('h2',{'class':'css-m604qf'})
        job_title = job_title[0].text.strip()
        
        company = container.findAll('a',{'class':'css-17s97q8'})
        company = company[0].text.strip()
        job_type = container.findAll('span',{'class':'css-1ve4b75 eoyjyou0'})
        job_type = job_type[0].text.strip()
        
        csv_output.writerow([job_title, company, job_type])
```